# SQL Get count of users who participated in a survey

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I want to know how I can write a SQL query to get the count of users who participated in each month survey

The table structures are like below

**SurveyTable**

```
SurveyId, SurveyName, Datetime
```

**SurveyInfo**

```
Id, SurveyId, First name, Last name DateTime
```

Sample Data

**SurveyTable**

```
1  Survey-ABC 1 Jan 2011
2  Survey-AXC 1 Feb 2011
3  Survey-AEW 1 Mar 2011
4  Survey-AVD 1 Apr 2011
....
```

**SurveyInfo**

```
1  1  Peter James 1 Jan 2011
2  1  John Tom    1 Jan 2011
3  1  Harry Kin   1 Jan 2011
4  2  Amber Wills 1 Feb 2011
5  2  Tom Kin     1 Feb 2011
```

I want a result like

- 3 users participated in Survey-ABC,
- 2 users participated in Survey-AXC

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT stab.Name, COUNT(si.ID)
FROM SurveyTable as stab INNER JOIN SurveyInfo si ON si.SurveyId = stab.SurveyId
GROUP BY stab.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    Count(*) AS "Number of participants", 
    SurveyTable.surveyName 
FROM 
    surveyinfo 
INNER JOIN surveytable 
    ON surveytable.surveyid = surveyinfo.surveyid 
GROUP BY 
    Year(DateTime),
    Month(Date_Time)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following select statement

```
SELECT st.Name, COUNT(si.ID)
FROM SurveyTable.st INNER JOIN SurveyInfo si ON si.SurveyId = st.SurveyId
GROUP BY st.Name
```

should provide you with the users who participated in the surveys.

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to see the number or participant for each month, so you need to extract the month and group by this.

```
SELECT SurveyTable.SurveyId, SurveyTable.SurveyName, Month(SurveyInfo.DateTime) As M, COUNT(SurveyInfo.*) As Cnt
FROM SurveyTable
LEFT JOIN SurveyInfo ON SurveyInfo.SurveyId = SurveyTable.SurveyId
GROUP By SurveyTable.SurveyId, SurveyTable.SurveyName, Month(SurveyInfo.DateTime)
```